# Obtain ascii values of chars in C#

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, razor

I am accustomed to coding in java, but recently I have been making some ASP webpages that use C#.

In Java chars are default represented by their numeric ascii value unless you put them with a string. I have been unable to repeat this in C#.

What do I need to do to get ascii values of chars in C#?

Comment: Like Java, .NET uses Unicode/UTF-16, not ASCII. Like Java, .NET's strings are a counted sequence of UTF-16 code-units that represent an uncounted number of Unicode codepoints. Like Java, .NET has a char type that holds a code-unit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[char](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Char%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in .Net is a 2-byte structure representing a UTF-16 encoding of a [unicode code point](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=unicode+code+point&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t) - of which ASCII is a tiny subset.  But some unicode code points including certain Kanji  characters require more than two bytes, and these are represented in a .Net string as a [surrogate pair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.issurrogatepair%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Thus the most general way to get an unicode code point value for a character in a string at a specified index is [`Char.ConvertToUtf32(string s, int index)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2ys180b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

For instance, the following enumerates the unicode code point values in a string:

```
    public static IEnumerable<int> Utf32CodePoints(string s, int index)
    {
        for (int length = s.Length; index < length; index++)
        {
            yield return char.ConvertToUtf32(s, index);
            if (char.IsSurrogatePair(s, index))
                index++;
        }
    }
```

If you explicitly want only ASCII values and want to skip non-ASCII characters, you could use the ASCII decoder with appropriate exceptions, as shown here: [Encoding.ASCII Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Alternatively, just cast each char to an int and check if its value falls between U+0000 and U+007F, which is the defined range for ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

[ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is very small subset of characters that can be represented in C#/Java.

Fastest way to get ASCII code (assuming you *know* that value fits in ASCII range):

```
var ascii = ((int)c) & 0x7F;
```

You may want to add range checks (0-0x7F) and fail if value falls outside the range. Alternatively you can use `Encoding.ASCII` to do conversion (will replace characters outside of the range with question marks).

Note: if your "ascii" actually mean "numeric value"/UTF-16 Unicode code than basic cast to `ushort` (or `int`) will work:

```
 var code = (int)c;
```